# Web grid MVC 3- If syntax for checking a condition

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a syntax error here, Could any one point out what is this please?

I have ViewBag.IsAdmin from the Controller

```
//code- I am writing this in a view-webgrid
grid.Column(format : (item) => {
                                 if(ViewBag.isAdmin)
                                  {

                                          Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditSingleAbsence","Absence", new { AbsenceId = item.id }, null);
                                  }
                               }
          )    
/code ended
```

It compalines with this error:

```
  CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments
```

I have found answer from here

[Here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1669919/4371225.aspx/1?WebGrid%20conditional%20content)
**Solution**

No Need to use if condition..

```
grid.Column(format:(item) => ViewBag.isAdmin ? Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditSingleAbsence", "Absence", new { AbsenceId = item.id }, null) : Html.Raw(""))
```

Comment: First, I'm fairly certain that Lambda expressions like that are still unavailable for Razor. (But I haven't checked in a while) Second. You might want to put your solution below as an answer and mark it as such. :)

Comment: what all I can say as newbie to razor is the above code is working. I will post the solution as answered.

Comment: Pretty sure all you needed to do was add a `return` statement to your `Html.ActionLink` and it would have worked :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Working Solution**

after Googling this worked for me. I got this solution from [Here](http://forums.asp.net/p/1669919/4371225.aspx/1?WebGrid%20conditional%20content)

```
grid.Column(format:(item) => ViewBag.isAdmin ? Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EditSingleAbsence", "Absence", new { AbsenceId = item.id }, null) : Html.Raw(""))
```